# How to paste values only in Excel using Python and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, copy-paste

I have an Excel worksheet.
In column J i have some some source data which i used to make calculations in column K.
Column K has the values I need, but when i click on a cell the formula shows up.
I only want the values from column K, not the formula.
I read somewhere that i need to set data only=True, which I have done.
I then pasted data from Column K to Column L(with the intention of later deleting Columns J and K).
I thought that Column L will have only the values from K but if i click on a cell, the formula still shows up.
How do I simply paste values only from one column to another?

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('edited4.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

last_row = 100  
for i in range(2, last_row):
    cell = "K" + str(i)
    a_cell = "J" + str(i)
    sheet[cell] = '=IF(' + a_cell + '="R","Yes","No")'

rangeselected = []
for i in range (1, 100,1):
    rangeselected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 11).value)
for i in range (1, 1000,1):
   sheet.cell(row=i, column=12).value = rangeselected[i-1]

wb.save('edited4.xlsx')
```

Comment: When you say "I then pasted data" do you actually mean pasting data or do you mean you programmatically transferred the data?

Comment: I programmatically pasted. The code is attached. Column =11 is referring to column K and Column= 12 is column L.

Comment: Openpyxl does not contain a copy of Excel's formula engine. That means unless Excel is opened, any formulas will not be resolved and only the formula is available. You should carry out the calculations in Python and insert the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used openpyxl. But:

Openpyxl doesn't run an Excel formula. It reads either the formula string or the results of the last calculation run by Excel*. This means that if a calculation is created outside of Excel, and the file has never been open by Excel, then only the formula will be available. Unless you need to display (for historical purposes, etc.) what the formula is, you should do the calculation in Python - which will be faster and more efficient anyway.

* When I say Excel, I also include any Excel-like spreadsheet that will cache the results of the last run.

Try this (adjust column numbers as desired):

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('edited4.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

last_row = 100  
data_column = 11
test_column = 12
result_column = 13

for i in range(2, last_row):
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=test_column).value == "R":
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=result_column).value = "Yes"
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=result_column).value = "No"

wb.save('edited4.xlsx')
```

If you have a well-formed data sheet, you could probably shorten this by another step or two by using enumerate() and Worksheet.iter_rows() but I'll leave that to your imagination.

Comment: Thanks Alan. It worked great. I really appreciate your assistance.